# How to merge a ".ts" file i have to my "home.ts"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, express

If I have a ".ts" file(prescription.ts) , with get and post and a home.ts file with get and post , Can I merge this .ts file to my home.ts file  , please guide me.
my codes:
for prescription.ts

```
import { AuthenticatedRequest,AuthenticatedRequestWithFile } from "./controller";
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
 


/**
 * Home page.
 * @route GET /
 */
router.get("/", async (req: AuthenticatedRequest, res: Response) => {
    res.render("ejs/index.ejs", {
        thanksMessage: false
    });
   
});

/**
 * Home page.
 * @route POST /
 */

router.post("/", async (req: AuthenticatedRequestWithFile, res: { redirect: (arg0: string) => any }) => {
    const prescription = req.files.prescription;
    console.log("Uploaded prescription",prescription);
    if (!prescription) {
      req.flash("errors", { msg: "prescription not uploaded. Try again!" });
      return res.redirect("back");
  }
    const extension = (prescription.name).split(".");
    if (!((extension[extension.length - 1]).toLowerCase() === "pdf" || (extension[extension.length - 1]).toLowerCase() === "bmp" || (extension[extension.length - 1]).toLowerCase() === "png" || (extension[extension.length - 1]).toLowerCase() === "jpg" || (extension[extension.length - 1]).toLowerCase() === "dib" || (extension[extension.length - 1]).toLowerCase() === "jpg" )){
        req.flash("errors", { msg: "Only upload images(.png,.bmp ,.dib,  .jpeg,.jpg,) or  PDFs, Try again!" });
        console.log("Coming out from extension check");
        return res.redirect("back");
    }
    
    prescription.mv(`${__dirname}/../../uploads/Prescription/${prescription.name}`, (err: any) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("logging in file uplaod error", err);
            req.flash("errors", { msg: "File not uploaded. Try again!" });
        } else {
            req.flash("success", { msg: "Thank you for submiting the Prescription :)" });
          
        }
      
        return res.redirect("back");
    });
});
 export default router;
```

And my home.ts :

```
import express from "express";
import { getUserCart } from "./cart";
import { AuthenticatedRequest } from "./controller"
import CallRequest from "../models/CallRequest"
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

/**
 * Home page.
 * @route GET /
 */
router.get("/", async (req: AuthenticatedRequest, res: Response) => {
    res.render("ejs/index.ejs", {
        thanksMessage: false
    });
    /*
    res.render("home.pug", {
        title: "Home",
        cartProducts: await getUserCart(req)
    });
    */
});

/**
 * Home page.
 * @route POST /
 */
router.post("/", async (req: AuthenticatedRequest, res: Response) => {
    console.log("Logging request body",req.body);
    CallRequest.create({ phone: req.body['your-email'] });
    res.render("ejs/index.ejs", {
        thanksMessage: true
    });
});

/**
 * Home page.
 * @route GET /
 */
router.get("/test", async (req: AuthenticatedRequest, res: Response) => {
    res.render("ejs/index.ejs", {
        title: ""
    });
});
export default router;
```

I want to have my prescription.ts 's code also in home.ts please guide me. Thanks.. so much
: ) : )

Comment: Export the functions or class from one file to other file.

Comment: Hi there thanks for reply can you please elaborate a bit like i have not used classes in my prescription.ts file and have used only router methods so when 
 i tried to put my prescription.ts code inside an export class  and then import on home.ts , it is giving errors by doing so ; maybe because of the router.get etc are there in the file i want to import , Can you please guide me. what to do in such .ts files

Comment: Do you want to just combine both the files

Comment: thanks for replying ,Yess ,I wanted them in one file only , btw , I have just now understood what I was doing incorrectly and solved ,Actually I had forgotten , to keep separate routes path('/ ... ') for the merged router methods : / :  / hence when i merged (simply added their codes ) only either of them were working ....